# Finite difference scheme in Matlab

Tags: matlab, finite-difference

I am trying to implement a finite difference scheme for KdV equation in MATLAB, and I have most of the code ready, except for approximation at the first level using initial condition. It was suggested I use Euler's method to obtain 'u' at m=1, and then use the scheme for m>=2.
How does one apply Euler's method in this context? Even just a general answer for approximation at the first level would be appreciated.
I am including my code for reference

```
 close all
 clear
 clc
% Generating grid with n points, with the space between two points being
%(x2-x1)/(n-1)
x = linspace(-5,5,1001); 
N=1001;
h=x(2)-x(1); % grid size
dt=0.05;
%Soliton initial condition
Am=8; %Amplitude
mu=sqrt(Am/2);
x0=-15;
c=1;
syms H(x)
H(x)=piecewise(x < 0,0,x > 0,1);
u= Am*(sech(mu*(x'-x0))).^2+c^2*H(x);

% Creating a matrix A - First order
A = diag(ones(N-1,1),1)-diag(ones(N-1,1),-1);
Cvector = zeros(N, 1);
Cvector(end) = 1;
u_ic = Cvector;

% First order finite difference scheme
diff_first=A*u/(2*h)+1/(2*h)*u_ic;

% Weighted average matrix for the term 'u'
A_w = diag(ones(N-1,1),1)+diag(ones(N-1,1),-1)+diag(ones(N,1));
diff_w=2*A_w*u +2*u_ic;

% Matrix multiplication of first derivative and weighted average for 6uu_x
diff_middle=diff_first.*diff_w;

% Creating a Third Order Matrix
r = zeros(1,N);
r(2:3) = [-2,1];
c = -r;
A_third = toeplitz(c,r);

% Difference scheme for third order term
diff_third=A_third*u/(h*h*h)-1/(h*h*h)*u_ic;

%Computing finite difference method
u = u - 2*dt*diff_middle-dt*diff_third;
plot(u)
```